# Android Screen orientation Edit text show set error?

Tags: android, android-orientation, android-screen

I'm new to android and making an app in which there is layout design for both portrait and landscape mode. The app is running fine in both screen orientation.
in this app I have set the validation on the edit text and show the error trough **set Error().** this work fine but when i try to rotate the orientation with blank field in edit text the **set Error()** method set error 
. I tried to solve this in different ways through Google search but didn't succeed. Please help me. Thanks

**below is the my Code**

```
EditText name, email, phone_no, subject, message;
    Button send;
    JSONObject json;
    final Context context = this;
    String valid_name = " ", valid_phone_no = " ", valid_email = " ",
            valid_sub = " ", valid_msg = " ";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
    Boolean isrotaion = false;
    static boolean et_focus;
    String emailPattern = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contact_us);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtname);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtemail);
        phone_no = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtphone);
        subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtsubject);
        message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtmessage);
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color
                .parseColor("#0f567c")));
        setTitle("Contact us");


        send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (valid_name != null && valid_email != null
                        && valid_phone_no != null && valid_sub != null
                        && valid_msg != null) {
                    isInternetPresent = isConnected();
                    if (!isInternetPresent) {

                        buildAlertMessageNonet();
                    } else

                    {
                        new CreateContact().execute();

                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please Fill up all Fields Correctly.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        });


        int orientation = this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            // code for portrait mode
            isrotaion = true;
        } else {
            // code for landscape mode
            isrotaion = true;
        }

        name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                validtion_name(name);

            }
        });
        email.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("TAG", "betextchange");
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                validation_Email(email);

            }
        });
        phone_no.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                validation_Phone_no(10, 13, phone_no);

            }
        });
        subject.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                validation_Subject(subject);

            }
        });

        message.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                validation_Message(message);

            }
        });
    }

    public void validtion_name(EditText edt) throws NumberFormatException {
        Log.i("TAG", "name");

        Log.i("TAG", String.valueOf(edt.length()));
        if (edt.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0) {
            edt.setError("Accept Alphabets Only.");
            valid_name = null;
        } else if (edt.getText().toString().contains(" ")) {
            edt.setError(null);
        } else if (!edt.getText().toString().matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
            edt.setError("Accept Alphabets Only.");
            valid_name = null;
        } else if (edt.getText().toString().charAt(0) == ' ') {
            edt.setError("First Letter Not be Space ");
            valid_name = null;

        } else {
            valid_name = edt.getText().toString();
        }

    }

    public void validation_Phone_no(int MinLen, int MaxLen, EditText edt)
            throws NumberFormatException {

        if (edt.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
            edt.setError("Numbers Only");
            valid_phone_no = null;
        } else if (edt.getText().toString().length() < MinLen) {
            edt.setError("Minimum length " + MinLen);
            valid_phone_no = null;

        } else if (edt.getText().toString().length() > MaxLen) {
            edt.setError("Maximum length " + MaxLen);
            valid_phone_no = null;

        } else if (edt.getText().toString().charAt(0) == ' ') {
            edt.setError("First Number Not be Space");
            valid_phone_no = null;
        } else if (!edt.getText().toString().matches("^[+]?[0-9]{10,13}$")) {
            edt.setError("Invalid Number");
            valid_phone_no = null;

        }

        else {
            valid_phone_no = edt.getText().toString();

        }

    }

    public void validation_Email(EditText edt) {

        if (edt.getText().toString() == null) {
            edt.setError("Invalid Email Address");
            valid_email = null;
        } else if (isEmailValid(edt.getText().toString()) == false) {
            edt.setError("Invalid Email Address");
            valid_email = null;
        } else if (edt.getText().toString().charAt(0) == ' ') {
            edt.setError("First Letter Not be Space");
            valid_email = null;
        } else if (!edt.getText().toString().matches(emailPattern)) {
            edt.setError("Invalid Email Address");
            valid_email = null;
        } else {
            valid_email = edt.getText().toString();
        }
    }

    boolean isEmailValid(CharSequence email) {
        return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
    }

    public void validation_Subject(EditText edt) {
        if (edt.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            edt.setError("Subject not be Empty ");
            valid_sub = null;
        } else if (edt.getText().toString().charAt(0) == ' ') {
            edt.setError("First Letter Not be Space");
            valid_sub = null;
        } else {
            valid_sub = edt.getText().toString();
        }
    }

    public void validation_Message(EditText edt) {
        Log.i("TAG", "maessage");
        if (edt.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            edt.setError("Message not be Empty ");
            valid_msg = null;

        } else if (edt.getText().toString().charAt(0) == ' ') {
            edt.setError("First Letter Not be Space");
            valid_msg = null;
        } else {
            edt.setError(null);
            valid_msg = edt.getText().toString();
        }
    }
```

**Also define orination in manifest**

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.my.Home"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.my.Careers"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.my.Services"
            android:configChanges="orientation" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.my.Contact_us"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.my.View_service"
            android:configChanges="orientation" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.my.Direction"
            android:configChanges="orientation" >
        </activity>
```

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you change the orientation all the views are regenerated. The OnCreateView method is called again and the TextChangedListener is again added to the editText View which calls its method and ultimately setError is called on blank editText.
To check if the screen orientation was changed and nothing was entered in EditText, we can use the Bundle that is passes in OnCreate() method of activity, if the activity is newly created this bundle is null but when screen orientation is changed its not null.
Check out the below code, I have implemented it for name EditText only, but I guess you will have to do the same for all EditText Views as it depends on which view the cursor is while orientation change.
Declare a bundle as a class member as,

```
    Bundle mSavedInstanceState;
```

and save the passed bundle in it in OnCreate() method as,

```
        if(savedInstanceState != null){
        this.mSavedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
    }
```

now use this bundle while checking error, if its orientation change(i.e. bundle won't be null) don't show the error...
Replace your code with below,
P.S.Some conditions were wrong, I have fixed them,
Hope it helps..!
Let me know if it works for you, and mark it as an answer so that it would be useful to others.

```
    public void validtion_name(EditText edt) throws NumberFormatException {
    Log.i("TAG", "name");

    Log.i("TAG", String.valueOf(edt.length()));
    if (edt.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0 && mSavedInstanceState ==null) {
        edt.setError("Accept Alphabets Only.");
        valid_name = null;
    } else if (edt.getText().toString().contains(" ")) {
        edt.setError(null);
    } else if (edt.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && !edt.getText().toString().matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
        edt.setError("Accept Alphabets Only.");
        valid_name = null;
    } else if (edt.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
        if(edt.getText().toString().charAt(0) == ' '){
            edt.setError("First Letter Not be Space ");
            valid_name = null;
        }
    } else {
        valid_name = edt.getText().toString();
    }
    }
```